Example of multitenant with generic host in C#
I have not found a solution (or example of) using multitenancy with a generic host in C#.
The examples given in the Autofac repository (ConsoleApp, MVC and WCF) uses a strategy that is not supported (as I see it) with generic host (Autofac needs access to an IContainer instance to create multitenancy container(s)).
Is there a way to use multitenancy with generic host and Autofac?
Thanks!
I've read the examples in the Autofac github repository and experimented a bit, but did not find a solution.
Here are the links to the examples

Generic host
Console app
MVC app
WCF app

To be more concrete, this is a standard generic host example that is from the code when experimenting, and I've put comments to highlight the issue at hand
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Autofac.Multitenant;

using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace AutoFacMultiTenantExploration;

internal class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        AutofacServiceProviderFactory factory = new();

        var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(factory)
            .ConfigureServices(ConfigureServices)
            .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(ConfigureContainer)
            .UseConsoleLifetime()
            .Build();

        //var mtc = new MultitenantContainer(_myTenantIdentificationStrategy, IContainer instance needed here...);

        await host.RunAsync();
    }

    private static void ConfigureServices(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection collection)
    {
        //var mtc = new MultitenantContainer(_myTenantIdentificationStrategy, IContainer instance needed here...);

        collection.AddHostedService<HostedService>();
        collection.AddSingleton<MyTenantIdentificationStrategy>();
    }

    private static void ConfigureContainer(HostBuilderContext context, ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        //var mtc = new MultitenantContainer(_myTenantIdentificationStrategy, IContainer instance needed here...);

        builder.RegisterType<Logger>().As<ILogger>();
    }
}

// IContainer is not registered by the generic host, so it's not possible to inject an instance here with the service IHostedService
internal class HostedService(ILogger logger) : IHostedService
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger = logger;

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Starting hosted service");

        //var mtc = new MultitenantContainer(_myTenantIdentificationStrategy, IContainer instance needed here...);


        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Stopping hosted service");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
internal class Logger : ILogger
{
    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception? exception, Func<TState, Exception?, string> formatter)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Logger: {formatter.Invoke(state, exception)}");
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IDisposable? BeginScope<TState>(TState state) where TState : notnull
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

internal class MyTenantIdentificationStrategy : ITenantIdentificationStrategy
{
    public int Identity { get; set; } = 0;

    public bool TryIdentifyTenant(out object? tenantId)
    {
        tenantId = Identity;
        return true;
    }
}


You might want to add more details such as a concrete example to prevent your question from being closed. It currently is too generic to be suited for Stack Overflow.

Thanks, I've added more details to the question, and highlighted where an instance of IContainer may be needed, depending on where it's going to be used in the code.

Guys, examining the intention of the MultitenantContainer type in the Autofac code, makes it clear that to use multitenancy you have to resolve using a multitenant container. The app host created delivers an IContainer instance as the root, and not a multi tenant container as the root. It means that there is no way to use tenant strategy with the dynamic host, since we don't control the the root container (as I understand it right now). We control the root container in all the examples given (the links in the question that I provided).

The configured container in the example is a ContainerBuilder, and this builder instantiates a Container, as you can see by this link into the repository of Autofac.

The docs for ASP.NET Core integration show how this can work, but you might need to mold it a little to your needs. The Autofac.AspNetCore.Multitenant package is the key.
For example, you could do something like this:
public static class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(
               new AutofacMultitenantServiceProviderFactory(ConfigureMultitenantContainer))
            .ConfigureServices(ConfigureServices)
            .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(ConfigureContainer)
            .RunConsoleAsync();
    }


    private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Register things with MS DI.
    }

    private static void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder containerBuilder)
    {
        // Register things that are shared across all tenants.
    }

    private static MultitenantContainer ConfigureMultitenantContainer(IContainer container)
    {
        var strategy = new YourTenantIdStrategy();
        var multitenantContainer = new MultitenantContainer(strategy, container);
        // Register things for various tenants.
        return multitenantContainer;
    }
}


Yay Travis, I started to play around with service provider factory, and didn't know that the work was already done with the AspNetCore multitenant package. I'll continue to elaborate about it. Thanks

If this answered your question, please accept it as the answer so I get the credit for it!
